# Replace the leading space with &nbsp; with the same number of times using a PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace leading space with `&nbsp;` with the same number of occurrences.

**Explanation:**

If one leading space exist in the input then it should replace it with one `&nbsp;`.

If two leading spaces exist in input then it should replace with two `&nbsp;`s.

If n leading spaces are exist in the input then it should replace it with exactly n number of times with  .

Example 1:

```
My name is XYZ
```

Output:

```
&nbsp;My name is XYZ
```

Example 2:

```
  My name is XYZ
```

Output:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;My name is XYZ
```

How can I replace only leading spaces, using a PHP regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$len_before = strlen($str);
$str = ltrim($str, ' ');
$len_after = strlen($str);
$str = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $len_before - $len_after) . $str;
```

---

Using `preg_replace` there is also

```
$str = preg_replace('/^( +)/e', 'str_repeat("&nbsp;", strlen("$1"))', $str);
```

but note that it uses the `/e` flag.

See http://www.ideone.com/VWNKZ for the result.

Comment: that is not Regexp, but it is the best way and less heavy! +1

Comment: Don’t forget the *m* flag to have `^` match the begin of a line.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 6):

```
preg_replace('/\G /', '&nbsp;', $str);
```

`\G` matches the position where the last match ended, or the beginning of the string if there isn't any previous match.

Actually, in PHP it matches where the *next* match is supposed to begin. That isn't necessarily the same as where the previous match ended.

Comment: @All : Thanks folks for your response.
@Alan : I followed your approach.

I just wanted to know for better approach to follow which one is optimum, efficient among flag 'G', 'm' and 'e', so that i'll hv actual reason to use mentioned flags

Comment: Well, `m` allows the `^` to match at the beginning of a line as well as at the beginning of the string, so it's not relevant in this case.  `e` causes the replacement to be treated as code instead of as a static string.  That could get very expensive indeed, but in practice the code is usually short and quick.  Even so, `\G` will usually be the most efficient option.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
preg_replace('/^ +/m', '&nbsp;', $str);
```

[**You can test it here**](http://www.rubular.com/r/efyjIDxRNv).

Comment: The objective is to replace *each* of the leading spaces with `&nbsp;`.  You're replacing *all* of them with *one* `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @alan you are right. my bad... I hate slashes for delimiters, btw, why I use `#`..

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match with PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag set. The offset is the length of the "spaces". Then use str_repeat with the offset.